# SQL query on how to add value to every single item of a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL query. Recently, I am appointed to add value to a database table column. The table column type is varchar(300) with value e.g. `[0.2649, 0.2548, 0.4801]` and I would like to add 0.01 to every single item inside the list which is

From:

```
0.2649, 0.2548, 0.4801
```

To:

```
0.2749, 0.2648, 0.4901
```

That column is with each cell contains a comma delimited list inside square brackets.

Could I know how to use sql query to do so?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a column where each cell contains a comma delimited list inside square brackets.... Or the column is a JSON datatype?

Comment: Oh dear.. search for mysql split string as a starter ..and what mysq version are you on?

Comment: Probably to late but worth a read so you dont make this mistake again https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right

Comment: Parse to separate values. Add needed value. Reconstruct back. Use JSON_TABLE and JSON_ARRAYAGG.